# React hooks queries

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I have the following queries -

1. What's the difference between `useEffect`, `useMemo` and `useCallback` hooks ? I have gone through many examples and explanations but still am not clear on their difference. All I know is that each executes only when at least one of their dependencies change.
2. If `useRef` hook allows us to persist with values between re-renders, why not use a simple variable (not a state) for the same ? I read somewhere that if not changed manually, `useRef` will have the same value all the time. Can't we achieve this with a simple variable ?

Answer (score 1):

#### tl;dr

1. `useMemo` fired immediately, `useCallback` not.
2. local variables a not persisted between renders

#### Explained

`useMemo` and `useCallback` area really very same. The difference between them are mentioned in the hooks names.

`useMemo` is created for calculating some heavy things (like taking some very long list and mapping it in another) and storing it for some time – as documentation says React can drop `useMemo` result and make hook to run again. When component is rendering first time, all `useMemo`s continuously runs calculations and their results may be used during the render. When rendering next times (if no hook dependencies changed) React do not call passed function but just using memorized result.

`useCallback` is created just for preserving variable references to functions that is passed as first argument. It is very helpful when callback, created with that hook is passed to some children components cause persistent variable reference do not invalidates memorized components.

Small example:

```
const app = () => {
  console.log('app render starts')
  const title = React.useMemo(() => {
    console.log('running calcualtion!')
    return 'Hello world'
  }, [])
  console.log('app render continues')
  const handleClick = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log('handling click')
  }, [])
  console.log('app render continues again')

  return <div onClick={handleClick}>{title}</div>
}
/*
Output after mounting app:
- app render starts
- running calcualtion!
- app render continues
- app render continues again
And after clicking div:
- handling click
*/
```

##### About `useRef`

React functional components are functions that runs again on every component render. Without hooks that functions are totally pure and unable to contain any state or preserve variables value – all function-scoped variables are created on every render again.
Hooks know which component are currently being rendered, so hooks able to store some data about component and get it back when component re-rendered.

In lot of cases `useRef` really are just a way to persist value between renders. As described above, you can't achieve that with simple variables inside of component's function. It could be achieved with some global variable declared outside of component. It even may be better choice if variable value do not depends one component mount/unmount which are handled by `useRef`.